gatsby-Source-s3 localFile is consistently null
I configured gatsby-source-s3 to pull in s3 objects from a bucket. The objects are retrieved as expected with functioning urls, etc., however the localFile field is consistently null.
Checking the graphql explorer, I see that the actual files from my s3 bucket are never downloaded at build time. I am curious if the package has since changed its operation or if there is a misconfiguration in my setup. I have been using the presigned urls in the meantime, but they of course expire and are unusable in production.
Here is a copy of the relevant options in my gatsby-config.
Thank you for any help!
I am currently using:
Gatsby 5.13.5
gatsby-source-s3 4.1.3
react 18.2.0
typescript 5.3.3
{ resolve: 'gatsby-source-s3', 
    options: { 
        protocol: 'https',   
        download: true,    
        images: { 
            download: true, 
            quality: 100, 
            webp: true, 
        } , 
        host: 's3.amazonaws.com', 
        port: 443,
        localFile: {
           path: './src/images', 
        } ,         
        aws: {
          credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.PROD_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.PROD_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
           },
            region: process.env.PROD_AWS_REGION,
          },
    buckets: [process.env.PROD_AWS_BUCKET_NAME],
    },
  }
`

